# how to destructure array getting on hitting localhost endpoint in react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I am working on react app Everything works fine but when I hit localhost endpoint I get Array of my stored document in mongodb
so I wanna use map to create loop and for that I have to also pass key to the each child but how to perform this all,I am facing destructuring problem , I mean I am unable to do ,

my function to hit localhost is below

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
// import PostContext from '../context/posts/postContext'
import Footer from "./Footer";
import Post from "./Post";
import Sidebar from "./Sidebar";

const Posts = () => {
  const getAllPost = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/allposts", {
      method: "GET",
    });
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getAllPost();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <main className="main">
        <div className="container">
          <h4 className="heading">Posts</h4>
          <Post key={} />
        </div>
        <div className="sidebar">
          <h4 className="heading">Sidebar</h4>
          <Sidebar />
        </div>
      </main>
      <footer>
        <Footer />
      </footer>
    </>
  );
};

export default Posts;
```

I also want to write title to get title not this.that.title
please give me solution to handle this

Comment: You should set the retrieved data into some state instead of just logging it to the console

Comment: please paste your `console.log`

Answer (score 2):

first, create a state to store data `const [posts,setPosts]=useState([])`. then
write this code in `getAllPost()` function, `setPosts(data)` to store data you receive from API into state. Now go to html code, below `<>h4</>` tags and write this `{posts.map((post,index)=><Post key={index} post={post}>)}`. Then you can access `post` from props of `<Post/>` component.
**Edit: i assume your response from API is already an Array**